# Adding up amounts in a column for every non-blank entry in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with a formula to do the following.  Say I have a sheet like so:

```
X   100  1000
    200
    200
    500
Y   400  1250
    400
    300
    150
Z   430  910
    330
    150
```

I want to sum up column B for every non-blank cell in column A so that the result looks like above.  For example, the sum for A is 1000 so 1000 is placed in column C.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are fancy ways to do this, but a simple, intuitive way is to use a helper column.  Say your example is in A2:C12.  Use column D for a helper column that transforms the column A information to a readily usable form.  In D2, the formula would be:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),D1,A2)
```

Copy this down the column for all of the data rows.  It fills in the blanks with the value above it.

Then in C2, the formula would be:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",SUMIF(D$2:D$9,A2,B$2:B$9))
```

Change the row ranges to match your data, then copy this down the column.  For any row that has a value in column A, it sums the values in column B as long as column D has the same value.  You can hide column D or use a column that is out of view.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: So the one problem seems to be that, and I might be wrong, it relies on the distance between each non-blank cell being the same.  I tried it on my data and it either gave me just the value in B2 or the sum of all the balances for the whole column.

Comment: You're completely right, I made a small mistake.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: My bad.  I forgot to anchor the ranges in the formula.  See the edit.  Copying that down the page without the anchors would give you a different range for each row (which probably worked anyway because of the nature of the formula).

Comment: No worries, that's what was throwing me off initially.